# Is there a way to deal with values emitted for multiple observables independently, and then do stuff when all observables are complete?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, asynchronous, rxjs

I'm working with RXJS methods, and I want to deal with an emitted value (when the correspondent Observable is complete) and then somewhere else further in the code, keep track of the state of the same `Observable` (Complete, error, waiting...).

The first step was to work with `forkJoin`, and it works fine but I have to wait for all `Observable`s to be complete to do stuff and if I `subscribe` to a function `getStuff(x)`, the `Observable` is "consumed" and the `forkJoin` won't work anymore with it naturally.

```
Observable1 = getStuff(a); // API which returns an observable
Observable2 = GetStuff(b); // API which returns an observable
Observable3 = Getstuff(c); // API which returns an observable
Observable.forkJoin([Observable1, Observable2, Observable3])
  .subscribe(result => doStuff(result) )
```

I need to deal with all values emitted independently when each `Observable` is complete, and then, when **all** `Observable`s are complete, do some other stuff. Something that would look like :

```
getStuff(a).subscribe( x => doStuffwitha(x) );
getStuff(b).subscribe( x => doStuffwithb(x) );
getStuff(c).subscribe( x => doStuffwithc(x) );
Observable.forkJoin([getStuff(a), getStuff(b), getStuff(c)])
  .subscribe( result => doStuff(result) )
```

I didn't find a proper solution with `async`/`await`, `Promises` or RXJS methods.

Is there a way to do this without adding new "artificial" Promises or complex work-around in order to keep the code synthetic and readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next func in each subscribe block should fire when:

- 1 emits
- 2 emits
- 3 emits
- all are complete

Like this:

```
Observable1 = getStuff(a); // API wich returns an observable
Observable2 = getStuff(b); // API wich returns an observable
Observable3 = getstuff(c); // API wich returns an observable
ObservableAll = Observable.forkJoin([Observable1, Observable2, Observable3])

Observable1.subscribe((xa) => { console.log('1', xa) })
Observable2.subscribe((xb) => { console.log('2', xb) })
Observable3.subscribe((xc) => { console.log('3', xc) })
ObservableAll.subscribe((xa, xb, xc) => { console.log('all', xa, xb, xc) })
```

This stackblitz shows what I think you are trying to achieve https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-df2gmv

Comment: I think what he wants is to get the output from the observable so that he could do something with it's result, but at a later point subscribe to a `forkJoin` of all of them.

Comment: added a stackblitz

Comment: Simple and effective. The stackblitz is very useful, this is the best way to play with your answer. I'll use it next time I have an angular question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a `tap` operator instead of `subscribe`:

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getStuff(a).pipe( tap(x => doStuffwitha(x)) );
getStuff(b).pipe( tap(x => doStuffwithb(x)) );
getStuff(c).pipe( tap(x => doStuffwithc(x)) );
Observable.forkJoin([getStuff(a), getStuff(b), getStuff(c)])
  .subscribe( result => doStuff(result) )
```

Comment: You're right, but you need to pass `forkJoin` the observables returned by the calls to `pipe` instead of calling `getStuff` again.

Comment: This works as well (when `getStuff().pipe( ...)` is passed in forkJoin as @SiddAjmera said). The `pipe( tap () )` is not necessary in this specific case, but it might be useful in other circumstances